# Regex in python to extract certain codes

Tags: regex, python-3.x, data-extraction

I have written a regex in python to extract codes like:

I63.9 J45.909 M18.90 Z82.61 Z82.389 A030 A029 S87.02XD H4010X2 S12530K V675XXS

The regex which I am using is shown below:

```
import re
data="We have the following codes to extract, I63.9 J45.909 M18.90 Z82.61 Z82.389 A030 A029 S87.02XD H4010X2 S12530K V675XXS September 2018"
regular_expression=re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]\d{1,2}\.*\d{1,3}\w{0,2}',re.I)
result=value_1.findall(data)
print(result)
```

Can someone tell me if it is the perfect regex to extract these codes or what could be a better and more robust regex to extract the above codes?

Comment: This seems like a job better suited for `Split()`

Comment: is the requirement for code: an alphabet followed by 1 or 2 digits followed by 0 to n `.` followed by 1, 2 or 3 digits followed by 0,1 or 2 characters? none of the codes given in the sample needs the last `\w{0,2}` part of the regex

Comment: @Matt.G sorry for the confusion. Updated my question. There could also be codes like: S87.02XD H4010X2 S12530K V675XXS

Comment: @RobertHarvey I did not get you?

Comment: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/zW0OOq/1

Comment: @lagripe thank you! can you type it as answer so that I can mark it as answer?

Comment: u'r welcome, yes sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
pattern = r'[A-Z]+\d+(\.\d+)?(\w+)?'
```